# Animate Button Movement

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to animate the movement of two buttons on a Windows Form in VB.Net. The form is loaded with ShowDialog() from the main form. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub MoveButtons(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picLogo.Click
    Dim SLoc As Point = btnSearch.Location
    Dim CLoc As Point = btnCancel.Location

    txtSearch.Enabled = False
    txtSearch.Visible = False
    btnSearch.Text = "Add"

    For idx As Integer = 1 To 36
        SLoc.Y -= 1
        btnSearch.Location = SLoc
        CLoc.Y -= 1
        btnCancel.Location = CLoc
        Thread.Sleep(5)
    Next
End Sub
```

I originally coded it using the `Top` property, but the result is the same. The Cancel button slides up as expected, but the Search/Add button simply disappears from the bottom up, then jumps up to the proper position. This happens regardless of whether I change the button text. Apart from the obvious `Location` and `Text` properties, the two buttons are identical, except the Cancel button has `DialogResult` set to `DialogResult.Cancel`.

[image: Form screenshots]

Comment: I hate to say this but... put `Application.DoEvents()` before `Thread.Sleep(5)`

Comment: But really, don't. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't giving the UI any time to update itself properly. Although that `Thread.Sleep(5)` is vital to the timing of your loop, it is also putting the UI thread to sleep. You don't want to do that.

So an easy but uninformed fix is to put `Application.DoEvents()` in the loop. This will allow the UI to update itself. This should make your code work...

```
...
Application.DoEvents()
Thread.Sleep(5)
```

But if you do enough of this type of thing, you will notice your UI slows down. It will give a bad feel to the application. You never want to put the UI thread to sleep.

What you should do is take all the non-ui stuff off the UI. You can create a thread and put it there. Inside the thread, however, you'd need to [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) any UI calls back to the UI. Here's how

```
Private Sub MoveButtons(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picLogo.Click
    txtSearch.Enabled = False
    txtSearch.Visible = False
    btnSearch.Text = "Add"
    Dim moveThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf moveButtonsSub)
    moveThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub moveButtonsSub()
    Dim SLoc As Point = btnSearch.Location
    Dim CLoc As Point = btnCancel.Location
    For idx As Integer = 1 To 36
        SLoc.Y -= 1
        CLoc.Y -= 1
        Me.Invoke(
            Sub()
                btnSearch.Location = SLoc
                btnCancel.Location = CLoc
            End Sub)
        Thread.Sleep(5)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm not sure what you mean by "non-UI stuff off the UI" (I'll learn!) but your solution works perfectly. I moved the `For-Next` loop inside the `Sub()` though, and went back to using the `Top` property.

Comment: A windows forms application starts running on the UI thread (simplistic explanation). But if you have a more than one core cpu, you should do *minimal* processing on the UI thread. You accomplish this by spawning other, non-UI threads where you will do computations etc. However, you can't access UI elements i.e. Controls, from those non-UI threads. So you must call any code which access Controls on the UI thread (Control.Invoke). See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls) for more info.

Comment: OK, I get it. Interesting. That gives me something to think about for the rest of the application as well. Thanks.